# jquery use $(this) as parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I apologize for the title already, but I don't really know how to ask this question except by putting it as an example.

Let's say this is my HTML

```
<img class="balloon" color="yellow" src="img_1.png">
<img class="balloon" color="red" src="img_2.png">
<img class="balloon" color="red" src="img_3.png">
```

Now let's say I have a jQuery plugin `party()` and I would like to pass the color to the plugin for each `img`.

Is this the only way?

```
$('.balloon').each(function() {
    $(this).party({
        party_color:$(this).attr('color'),
        other_param1:'xyz',
        foo:'bar'
    });
});
```

Or could something like this work in any way?

```
$('.balloon').party({
    party_color:$(this).attr('color'),
    other_param1:'xyz',
    foo:'bar'
});
```

If I try this I get the `document`-element back. It's a shame, bacause the second approach seems more efficient to me. Is there a way I could reference the specific `img` in the parameter values directly? `$(this)` obvioously isn't working.

Comment: Extend the code and make the `party` code read the attribute.

Comment: A lot of plugins allow parameters to be functions for exactly this reason, so they allow stuff like `party_color: function() { return $(this).attr('color'); }` - is this your plugin?

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino Looked promosing, but `$(this)` still does not seem to be the matched element if you wrap it in a function..

Comment: @Jules: I only mentioned that some plugins support this, if the plugin doesn't support it then it doesn't support it and you have to do it the first way or modify the plugin. Not really a whole lot else to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the color inside the plugin, there's no need to use the elements attributes as options for the plugin when the elements are accessed in the plugin anyway ?

```
$('.balloon').party();

$.fn.party = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var this_party_color = $(this).attr('color');


        // the rest of the plugin

    });
}
```

Comment: I know, but my real life problem is more complex. I have to use the attribute of my elements as a key to look up another value in an array, which is not accessible by the plugin.

Comment: Then pass the array to the plugin ?

Comment: I could do that, but it's more logical that the code calling the plugin understands the array, and converts it to data the plugin can work with (in the form of parameters.) I know this question doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, but it's mainly because I want to gain some more insight in jQuery. I already have a working example (my first example), but somehow I have a feeling the second example should work too..

Comment: If you have an array that you intend to use for a plugin on a "each element" basis, in my opinion the more logical approach would be to make that array accessible to the plugins internal loop, and not loop twice to get the array values as parameters.

Comment: the array is not for the plugin alone. It contains a lot of data, and some of it will be used by the plugin. To be more precise. I'm writing a Wordpress plugin, and I'm passing a bunch of PHP variables to my javascript as an array. Some of the data is used to pass to jQuery plugins and javascript classes I didn't develop myself (so modifying the code to work with the array is not really an option.)

Comment: Well, you really can't pass parameters for each element in the collection, so your only option then would be the solution you already have, to call the plugin on each element in a loop, with a different parameter for each instance. It's inefficient, and not the way I would do it, but outside the plugin code, that would be your best option.

Comment: If you can not change it than you need to live with the each loop. end of story.